# Cakephp - After login and logout redirect, not reloading the page

Tags: session, cakephp, redirect, cakephp-2.0

In my app I have the login and logout actions

```
function login()
{
    $this->layout = 'cake';

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->Auth->login();
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect(array(
                'controller' => 'photos',
                'action' => 'flow'
            ));
        }

        else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Nome de usuário ou senha incorreto', 'default', array(
                'class' => 'flash_fail'
            ));
        }
    }

}
```

But, when user login, and goes to `photos/flow` the user name don't appears. I need to refresh the page(F5) to show users info.
There's a way to redirect and refresh the informations?
Thanks.

Comment: Why using `$this->Auth->login();` twice? This is a definite killer :) The second will always return false.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'photos','action' => 'flow'));
        } else {
$this->Session->setFlash('something went wrong', 'flash', array('alert' => 'error'));
}
```